# Microphone.GetPosition breaks on Android on a certain scene

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I've run into a bit of a peculiar problem that I can just not solve. I have a pretty big problem I'm working on that requires the microphone for processing speech to text, which is then sent for further processing. Then I also use the microphone to determine the loudness of it.

This works great on PC, be it in editor or in a build. But on Android this completely breaks. `Microphone.Start` works fine and keeps working with the audio clip. But whenever I call `Microphone.GetPosition` it returns 0 at any time.

Odd thing is that it does work in empty scenes. But in a particular scene *something* breaks and I'm not sure what. I've tried going into the scene with every object disabled, and enabling them one by one but the microphone stops working immediately. Nothing else but the script that I've written touches the `Microphone` class so it should not be stopped. I'm not quite sure why `GetPosition` returns 0.

Is there something that conflicts with the microphone, causing `GetPosition` to return wrong numbers? Anyone has any idea?

Comment: can you include the relevant pieces of code where you make the calls to the microphone?

Comment: I'm afraid not. That's what makes this a difficult question to ask. But the calls are nothing special and just call `Microphone.Start` if it's not already recording. It restarts every scene, but only upon hitting this scene it stops working. The code is being called, and I even check if it's initialized properly by waiting 50 milliseconds and seeing if the position is above 0. But it never goes above 0. Restarting it doesn't work either.